# Unexpected behavior while opening escaped file:/// URL in IE

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, url

I could swear to god that the code below used to work a week ago. I can tell that because the software I develop depends on it.

This code chunk is supposed to open an html page from a local HDD using IE:

(These strings are not hardcoded in my actual example. What it does is this -- it escapes the path to the local html file and adds file:/// in front.)

```
LPCTSTR m_strBrowser = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
LPCTSTR addr2 = L"\"file:///C%3a%5cUsers%5cUserName%5cAppData%5cLocal%5cTemp%5cReport_View.htm\"";

ShellExecute(hMain, NULL, m_strBrowser, addr2, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

But what I get when I test it today is just the home page in IE.

Any idea what is wrong here?

PS. The `Report_View.htm` file exists in the file system.
PS2. If I copy and paste the escaped URL into Chrome or FF, it opens just fine.

Comment: "*the code below used to work a week ago*" Then `diff` with your previous version (you use version control software, *right*?).

Comment: @syam: There's no `diff` -- it wasn't changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, evidently they made some changes to the IE and now the file protocol URL can no longer contain arbitrary escaping. From my experience, the only way to make it work with IE is by getting the file protocol path by calling the [UrlCreateFromPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API:

```
//You get this path from Registry
LPCTSTR m_strBrowser = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";

LPCTSTR addr2 = L"C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Report_View.htm";

DWORD dwSz_buff_addr2 = INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH;
TCHAR buff_addr2[INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH];
if(SUCCEEDED(UrlCreateFromPath(addr2, buff_addr2, &dwSz_buff_addr2, NULL))
{
    ShellExecute(hMain, NULL, m_strBrowser, buff_addr2, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I'm not sure the parameter should be quoted in itself (it doesn't have space characters anyway), also not sure about the escaping.

Try:

```
LPCTSTR addr2 = L"file:///C|/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Temp/Report_View.htm";
```

Comment: It's supposed to be 3 slashes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731(v=vs.85).aspx and quotes should not make a difference.

Comment: My bad.  Are you sure about the escaping? (Editied my answer)

Comment: Well, the only thing I didn't do is replace : with |, but it still doesn't make any difference. As escaping goes it should not make any difference, but it does. If I remove escaping, it works. With it, it doesn't. Again, the same exact code worked a week ago. Is it one of those MS updates that messed something up?